# Excel VBA - Dictonary.Exists(Dictionary)?

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

Would like to better understand how keys of object type are compared. `dicOverall.exists(dic2)` returns `False` while `dicOverall.exists(dic1)` returns `True`. I am not too sure how `.Exists` compare stuff (loop?) but is there anyway I could get `.Exists(dic2)` to return `True`? Thank you!

```
Sub test()
    Dim dic1 As Object
    Dim dic2 As Object
    Dim dicOverall As Object


    Set dic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dicOverall = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    dic1("Hi") = 1
    dic1("Hello") = 1

    dic2("Hi") = 1
    dic2("Hello") = 1

    dicOverall(dic1) = 1

    Debug.Print dicOverall.exists(dic2)


End Sub
```

Comment: you would first have to add dic2 to dicOverall, before that it obviously doesn't exist in dicOverall

Comment: You need to add that key to dic2, that is what Exists is checking.

Comment: Add this line:  `dicOverall(dic2) = 1`

Answer (score 4):

I think if you do

```
dicOverall(dic1) = 1
```

then the only existing key in `dicOverall` is the object `dic1` and you ask if the key `dic2` exists in `dicOverall`? That answer can't be `true` it's always `false`.

`dic1` and `dic2` are 2 completely different objects even if they contain the same keys. The `.exists` doesn't compare the contents of these objects it just sees that these objects are different objects.

**Example:**
Let's say `.exists` checks if a specific object is in a box and you have 2 apples called `dic1` and `dic2`. If you put apple `dic1` into the box and check with `.exists` if apple `dic2` is in the box you get a no. `.exists` doesn't check if there is *an* apple in the box it checks if there is *a specific* apple named `dic2` is in the box. Even if they are both apples and look like the same.

```
Sub AppleExample()
    Dim apple1 As Object
    Dim apple2 As Object
    Dim box As Object

    Set apple1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set apple2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set box = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'apple1 has 1 stem and a red color
    apple1("stem") = 1
    apple1("redColor") = 1

    'apple2 has 1 stem and a red color
    apple2("stem") = 1
    apple2("redColor") = 1

    'put apple1 into the box
    box(apple1) = 1

    'check if apple2 is in the box
    Debug.Print box.exists(apple2)
End Sub
```

If you want to check if there is something in the box that looks like `apple1` but is actually `apple2` then you have to check all the properties (stem, color, …) themselves.

---

If you want to check if `dic1` has the same keys as `dic2` then you have to check …

1. if `dic1` and `dic2` have the same count of keys (necessary if `dic2` has all keys from `dic1` but plus other keys!)
2. if first is true then loop through all keys of `dic1` and check if every single key exists in `dic2`.

Here is a good resource about dictionaries: [VBA Dictionary](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) and [Using the Dictionary Class in VBA](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3391/Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html)

Comment: hey that was exactly what I was trying to achieve - to compare the keys for each dictionary. The reason why I have such a question is because, assuming I have `apple1 = "red"` and `apple2 = "red"`, the 2 separate variables should have different memory addresses. However, if I were to do `dic(apple1) = 1` and subsequently `dic.Exists(apple2)`, i believe i should get a `True`. By that extension, I was wondering if there's an easy way to compare 2 arrays or dictionaries by exploiting the `.Exists` method.

Comment: No, to compare the content of 2 dictionaries is not possible in the way you tried it. Therefore you have to loop through the dictionary like I showed in the last part of my answer. `dic.Exists(apple2)` will **never** be `true` if there is only `apple1` in your `dic` even if both are red.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - in the above comments `apple1` and `apple2` are strings and not objects. I was wondering if `.Exists` work for 2 string variables (with different memory addresses), why wouldnt it work for 2 objects? Since not working for objects is already proven, what does `.Exists` compare exactly? Thanks for your patience with this query! Edit: `apple1 = "red"` `apple2 = "red"`  `dicOverall(apple1) = 1` `Debug.Print dicOverall.Exists(apple2)`

Comment: If they are strings they do not have to be the same address at all, `exists` compares the strings then. But for objects they need to point to the same address. This is just due to that objects can be anything (not only dictionaries) they are more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to get `.Exists(dic2)` to return `True` is to set `dic2` to refer to `dic1` - so under the hood `dic1` and `dic2` are just pointers to the *same* underlying object.

Then - even if you never do `dicOverall.Add dic2, 1` you will still get `True` if you do `dicOverall.Exists(dic2)`.

It is all rather lacking a real life application - but useful if you are playing around with dictionaries. In this sample code you will see the use of `Set dic2 = dic1` to make them point to the same underlying dictionary. And that changing a value of `dic2` also changes it in `dic1` - showing they are pointers to the same thing.

Then the check for `dic2` being a key of `dicOverall` will return `True`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim dic1 As New Dictionary
    Dim dic2 As New Dictionary
    Dim dicOverall As New Dictionary

    'add items to first dictionary
    dic1.Add "foo", "bar"
    dic1.Add "baz", "qux"
    'make second refer to first
    Set dic2 = dic1
    'add first dictionary to overall
    dicOverall.Add dic1, 1

    'change a value in 2nd dictionary and see 1st dictionary change too
    Debug.Print dic1.Item("baz")
    dic2.Item("baz") = "hello world"
    Debug.Print dic1.Item("baz")

    'shows 1 for both dictionaries
    '*even though you never added dic2 to dicOverall*
    Debug.Print dicOverall.Exists(dic1)
    Debug.Print dicOverall.Exists(dic2)

End Sub
```

My debug output:

```
qux
hello world
True
True
```

Comment: but when you do this and add a key to `dic1` it is added to `dic2` too. Then you only have 2 names for one thing isn't it?

Comment: Yes. In my answer `dic1` and `dic2` are pointers to the same dictionary. Its an answer to the question but struggling to think why you would do it in a real life application. Otherwise the OP question just gets the answer 'no - you need to add `dic2` to `dicOverall`'. Your point about the dictionaries looking the same but not being the same is the inverse of my answer where I actually *make them the same*

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too. You are correct. I just think the OP thought `.exists` checks if all the keys of `dic1` exist in `dic2`. Just want to make sure that the difference is clear. In your example `dic1` and `dic2` **are the same** and in OPs example  `dic1` and `dic2` **have the same contents but are different objects**.

Comment: I agree with your distinction. Now that you mention it I agree the OP has misunderstood the nature of the `exists` function and thinks it can check that the objects have the same key/ value pairs.

Comment: Yes i believe i am making the mistake to think that .exists checks that the keys are the same. Could I trouble you guys and redirect to the comment in Peh's post to further correct my misunderstanding - does the `.Exists` method compare the memory addresses or what exactly does it compare? thanks a lot for all the help!